# Safari - HTML5 audio won't play when tab is in the background

Tags: javascript, audio, safari, notifications, html5-audio

I have a react app that uses react-sound (basically, HTML5 Audio) to play a sound when a new notification is triggered. I want this sound to play when the tab is backgrounded in Safari, however that does not seem to work.

The sound does play when the tab is in the foreground.

Does anyone know of a workaround for this?

Comment: Maybe it would help if you post your code.